# caffe: regression multi-dimensional output delivers weird results even though loss converges

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have a regression network with a `EculideanLoss` layer and after training my `loss` has a value about 3.

```
layer {
    name: "conv2"
    type: "Convolution"
    bottom: "conv"
    top: "conv2"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 1 # <-- this is correct right??
        kernel_size: 5
        pad: 2
        stride: 1
        ...
    }
}

layer {
    name: "relu"
    type: "ReLU"
    bottom: "conv2"
    top: "result"
    relu_param{
        negative_slope: 0.01
    }
}
```

[image]

My data is an image with dimensions: 1 x 128 x 128 and my .g`ground_truth` is also image with the same dimensions. I scale all values from [0, 255] -> [0, 1].

When I try to retrieve the `predicted image` my result delivers a weird image with does not even look like the `ground_truth`

My python script to retrieve the output looks like this:

```
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformer.preprocess('data', img)
pred = net.forward()
output_blob = pred['result']

predicated_image_array = np.array(output_blob)
predicated_image_array = predicated_image_array.squeeze()

range_value = np.ptp(predicated_image_array)
min_value = predicated_image_array.min()
max_value = predicated_image_array.max()

# make positive
predicated_image_array[:] -= min_value

if not range_value == 0:
    predicated_image_array /= range_value

predicated_image_array *= 255

predicated_image_array = predicated_image_array.astype(np.int64)
cv2.imwrite('predicted_output.jpg', predicated_image_array)
```

Is a loss of value 3 too high or is something wrong with my python script?

Hint: When I use a `SoftmaxWithLoss` layer instead of the `EuclideanLayer` and dont scale the values from [0, 255]-> [0, 1] but rather leave them and let my labels be from [0, 255] I get a very decent result!

Comment: I think you can also keep values in [0,255] in regression.

Comment: When I do that my loss values are 2e¹⁰ but I will update my plot to show you! But apart from that can you find any mistakes in my `code` or `prototxt`? @Dale